# Solving $a!+b!+c!=3^d$

Tags: number-theory

The question is to find all tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ of natural numbers $c\geq b$ and $ b \geq a $ and $a!+b!+c!=3^d$. I am finding difficulty in establishing relation between $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. I see that a!,b!,c! are even.How can their sum be odd? Please help.

Comment: $1! + 1! +1! = 3^1$ ;)

Comment: @tatan You have a large number of questions asked with no answer accepted. Please, if any of the answers helped you, consider accepting them by clicking the tick-mark underneath the relevant upvote/downvote arrows.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: If $a$ and $b$ and $c$ are all greater than or equal to $2$, then the LHS is divisible by 2. Therefore, there are no tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ which satisfy the constraint, if $a \geq 2$.

Comment: And if $a = 1$ and $b \ge 3$, no solutions either for a similar reason.

Comment: And if $a=1$, $b=2$ then for $c \ge 6$ the RHS is divisible by $9$, while the LHS is not.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $a \geq 2$ then all your factorials are even, so you cannot have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

When $a \le b \le c$ we get

> $$
> a! + b! + c! = a! \Big( 1 + b!/a! \big( 1 + c!/b! \big) \Big) = 3^d. \tag 1
> $$

If $a \ge 2$ then there are no solutions.

If $b \ge 3$ then there are no solutions.

So we can only get

> $$
> 1 + 2 + c! = 3^d, \tag 2
> $$

thus

> $$
> c! = 3 \big( 3^{d-1} - 1 \big) \tag 3
> $$

But $3$ divides $c!$, so $3 \le c$.

But $3$ does not divide $3^{d-1} - 1$, so $c < 6$.

So

> $$
> 2 < c < 6. \tag 4
> $$

Verification

> $$
> 3! = 3 \Big( 3^{d-1} - 1 \Big) \Rightarrow 3^d = 9,\\ \tag 5
> 4! = 3 \Big( 3^{d-1} - 1 \Big) \Rightarrow 3^d = 27,\\
> 5! = 3 \Big( 3^{d-1} - 1 \Big) \Rightarrow 3^d = 123.\\
> $$

So the only solutions are

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] {
> \begin{array}{c}
> (1,2,3) \Rightarrow 1! + 2! + 3! = 3^2\\\\
> (1,2,4) \Rightarrow 1! + 2! + 4! = 3^3
> \end{array} } \tag 6
> $$

Answer (score 0):

In a similar way to other hints, if $b, c \ge 3$ then consider the factor $3$